# Confidence bounds for coefficients of a fit of data set obtained with another fit

Tags: curve-fitting, confidence-interval, coefficients, quadratic

I fitted an equation to a set of data points. Then I substracted the fit previously obtained to another set of data points. After that, I fitted another equation to this new data (result of the substraction). What happens with the confidence bounds of the coefficients of this new fit?
The two equations fitted are quadratic.

Comment: I would recommend asking this in https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok. I just did it. Thank you.